# HTML5 video continue playing after setting currentFrame

Tags: javascript, html

I need to jump to a specific time in a html5 video, but if I do

```
function jumpToTime(){
document.getElementById("videoclip").currentTime = 160;
};
```

then the playback stops. If I try to make it play again with

```
function jumpToTime(){  
document.getElementById("videoclip").currentTime = 160;
document.getElementById("videoclip").play();
};
```

then it goes back to the beginning and plays from there.

How can I jump to a point in time and keep playing from there?

Answer (score 0):

What if you pause before seeking?

```
document.getElementById("videoclip").pause();
document.getElementById("videoclip").currentTime = 160;
document.getElementById("videoclip").play();
```